# Apostol's proof of Arzelà's Bounded Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the first edition of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, there is a proof of Arzelà's bounded convergence theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem 13-17}\,(\textit{Arzel}\grave{a})\textbf{.}$ Assume that $\lbrace f_{n}\rbrace$ is a uniformly bounded, pointwise convergent on $[a,b]$ and suppose that each $f_{n}$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$. Suppose also that the limit function $f(x):=\lim_{n}f_{n}(x)$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$. Then,
$$ \lim_{n}\int_{[a,b]}f_{n}=\int_{[a,b]}\lim_{n}f_{n}=\int_{[a,b]}f. $$
$\textit{Proof}.$ Let $g_{n}(x)=\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|$. We will prove that
$$ \lim_{n}\int_{[a,b]}g_{n}=0. $$
For this purpose we define a new sequence of functions $\lbrace h_{n}\rbrace$ as follows:
$$ h_{n}(x)=\sup_{m\ge n}f_{m}(x),\qquad\text{ if }x\in[a,b]\text{ and }n\in\mathbf{N}. $$
Note that, for each fixed $x$, we have
$$ 0\le g_{n}(x)\le h_{n}(x),\qquad h_{n+1}(x)\le h_{n}(x),\qquad \lim_{n} h_{n}(x)=0. $$
Hence, $0\le\int_{[a,b]}g_{n}=\mathop{\underline{\int}}_{[a,b]}g_{n}\le\mathop{\underline{\int}}_{[a,b]}h_{n}.$ (The lower integral $\mathop{\underline{\int}}_{[a,b]} h_{n}$ exists because each $h_{n}$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. However, $h_{n}$ need not to be Riemann-integrable. On the other hand, $g_{n}$ $\textit{is}$ Riemann-integrable, since both $f_{n}$ and $f$ are integrable.) Let $I_{n} = \mathop{\underline{\int}}_{[a,b]} h_{n}$. The proof will be complete if we can show that $I_{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Observe that the sequence $\lbrace I_{n}\rbrace$ convergs to $\textit{some}$ non-negative limit. Let $I=\lim_{n}I_{n}$. We will show that the inequality $I>0$ leads to a contradiction.
Assume that $I>0$. Since $I_{n}\ge I > I/2$ for each $n$, there is a partition $P_{n}$ of $[a,b]$ and a lower Riemann sum $L(P_{n},h_{n})$ such that $L(P_{n},h_{n})>I/2.$ Let $\varepsilon=\tfrac{1}{2}I/(M+b-a)$, where $M$ is a uniform bound for $\lbrace h_{n}\rbrace$ on $[a,b]$. The lower sum $L(P_{n},h_{n})$ can be split into two parts as follows:
$$ L(P_{n},h_{n})=\sum_{i\in A_{n}}m_{i}(h_{n})\Delta x_{i}+\sum_{i\in B_{n}}m_{i}(h_{n})\Delta x_{i}, $$
where $m_{i}(h_{n})$ denotes the $\inf$ of $h_{n}$ in the $i$th subinterval of $P_{n}$ and
$$ A_{n}=\lbrace i: m_{i}(h_{n})>\varepsilon\rbrace,\quad B_{n}=\lbrace i:m_{i}(h_{n})\le\varepsilon\rbrace. $$
The inequality $L(P_{n},h_{n}) >I/2$ implies
$$ \tfrac{1}{2} I <\sum_{i\in A_{n}}M\Delta x_{i}+\varepsilon\sum_{i\in B_{n}}\Delta x_{i}\le M\sum_{i\in A_{n}}\Delta x_{i}+\varepsilon(b-a), $$
from which we obtain $\sum_{i\in A_{n}}>\varepsilon$. Since refinement of partitions increases lower sums, there is no loss in generality in assuming that the $P_{n}$ are such that $P_{n}\subset P_{n+1}.$
Now let $S_{n}$ denote the union of these subintervals $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ of $P_{n}$ for which $i\in A_{n}$. Then $S_{n}$ is a closed set and its Jordan content is
$$ c(S_{n})=\sum_{i\in A_{n}}\Delta x_{i}>\varepsilon. $$
This implies that there is ate least one $x$ belonging to infinitely many of the sets $S_{n}$. Hence, for this $x$ we have $h_{n}(x)>\varepsilon$ infinitely often, contradicting the fact that $h_{n}(x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, $I=0$.

---

Why does $c(S_{n})>\varepsilon$ for all $n$ imply that there exists some $x$ such that $x\in S_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$? Apostol doesn't prove this, but this claim doesn't seem to be entirely obvious. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you meant to say $h_n(x)=\sup_{m \geq n}f_m(x)-f(x)$, otherwise I don't see how $\lim_n h_n(x)=0$

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice proof of this fact in this paper [De Silva](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.1439.pdf). The author takes $U_n$ to be $S_n$ minus the endpoints of all subintervals, so the sets $U_n$ are open. Then defines $V_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}U_k$ and proves that the intersection of the set $V_n$ is nonempty. See also the paper of [Luxenburg](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/335_16/dominated.pdf).  The fact you want is Theorem B. Apparently there was a mistake in Arzela’s proof of that theorem, which he fixed later. There seems to be a simpler proof but it is in a paper in German.

Comment: the paper of Luxemburg URL doesn't work for me

Comment: @Shthephathord23 Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at "[A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis (2nd ed.)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-01400-1_10)" by Ghorpade and Limaye. Also, "[Arzelà's Bounded Convergence Theorem](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/anly-2023-0034/html?lang=en)" by Saric is probably the most straightforward proof that you will find. Both are based on Hausdorff's method, just like Luxemburg's whose version is very difficult to understand for an average student.